# MusicProperties why null?

Tags: c#, windows, properties, windows-store-apps, storage

My code part is here. I have a class for list.

```
StorageFolder libraryFolder = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary ;
        IReadOnlyList<IStorageItem> fileList = await libraryFolder.GetItemsAsync();
        foreach (StorageFile file in fileList)
        {
            MusicProperties properties = await file.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
           .......
```

And i get null value in here.

```
 MusicProperties properties = await file.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
```

Do someone know that?

Comment: What is `null` exactly? I see two dots there.. one of the preceding objects would be `null`... Perhaps you could debug it and step into the code?

Comment: null means nothing. I write properties to textboxt in gridview template. string is empty and integers in 0.

Comment: What variable is null? file or Properties? Or something inside the GetMusicPropertiesAsync() method?